# How to redirect the login page if user is not authenticated when a kendo window opens

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-identity

I am using Kendo UI in jquery and MVC 5, for authentication using ASP.net identity.

Manywhere i am opening view (page) in Kendo Window as code below :

```
$("#divTemp").kendoWindow({
    title: "ABC",
    width: 50px,
    height: 50px,
    draggable: false,
    actions: ["Close"],
    content: {
        url: ../master/bank,
    },
    modal: true,
    iframe: false,
    //refresh: false,
    resizable: true,
    visible: false       
}).data("kendoWindow").center().open();
```

I would like to redirect to login page if user is unauthorized. I have implemented code this but login page opening in kendo window instead of redirect main login page.

If anyone have any solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a number of things:

1. Move the logic to check if the user is logged in to the action method of the page that holds the window logic.
2. Change the logic on the action method called by the window for its content to show a different view if the user is not logged in saying something like “Not logged in, please click here to login” which takes the user back to the login page.
3. Listen to the kendo window open event and create a function that checks if the user is logged in and if not redirects them to the login.
4. If the opening of the window is triggered by a button have two versions of the button. One that renders if the user is logged in one of they are not. If logged in the button could open the window and if not then the button can take them to the login page.